# Adding ridges to a non-flat surface

Tags: modeling, modifiers

I'm trying to model this vase

[image]

It's 10-fold radially symmetric, so I

1. model half of one "face" (shown below)
2. apply mirror to get the entire face
3. apply subdivision for smoother look
4. array 10-fold around an empty rotated by 36 degrees

[image]

which gets me here:

[image]

However I still don't know how to add the ridges visible in the reference image. There are a plenty answers on adding ridges on Blender SO, but it's usually in cases when the surface is rather simple, for instance circular.

1. I can imagine some tool like `bridge edge loops` except bridging with an object pattern rather than flat faces and then use that with the two loops highlighted on the *one half* image above.
2. Alternatively I could somehow `array` a cylinder along the left edge loop (although that wouldn't adjust their length and angle properly, in order to reach the other edge loop perfectly).
3. Finally, I could use some tool to subdivide the faces between the two edge loops into height-wise equispaced faces and manually extrude every 2nd along normals.
   Unfortunately I'm not aware of any tools to achieve equidistant subdivision.

One requirement I have is that the ridges have to be *seamlessy* merged with the body, since I'm using a transparent material and internal faces would cause weird reflections. Additionally, the ideal solution would be procedural (modifiers) but a destructive one would also work for me.

Comment: What about a procedural displacement (or bump) shader?

Comment: I didn't think of it (new to blender). Would it simulate the caustics correctly (or at least plausibly)? Wouldn't it require some UV mapping wizardry to make it space correctly on this strip of faces? How would I go about it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As Hiserod says, normal map would make it lighter, but if you want to model the grooves for real (but you could also bake them at the end), you could begin with this type of shape (mirrored), shift it from its origin:

[image]

Give it the following modifiers: *Array* (vertically), *Array* (around with an object offset), *Lattice, Subdivision Surface*, reshape with the lattice:

[image]

Apply the *Mirror*, the vertical *Array* and the *Lattice*, in *Edit* mode select all the faces that need to be extruded to create grooves:

[image]

Extrude along Y, flat individual faces on Y with *Transform Pivot Point* set to *Individual Origins*. You could also keep the lattice and extrude but it would badly deform the extrusions, thus the different *Apply*:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, it's a great idea with 2x array!

Comment: a bit high-poly at the end though, so maybe bake the normals and use a low-poly